# How does Koriand'r hide as Cory Anders?

Tags: dc, teen-titans

So, Koriand'r, aka [Starfire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starfire_(Koriand'r)), has golden skin. She's very distinctive in appearance, inhuman.
[image: Depicted on the cover of "The New Teen Titans" in 1980]

However, [as Cory Anders, model](http://www.gramunion.com/tazeyeview.tumblr.com/153706435093), she looks fairly normal, if quite exotic, and used that name as her secret identity.
[image: Cory Anders]

> Koriand'r escaped by stealing a spacecraft to flee to the nearest planet, Earth, where she met the first Robin and his compatriots; she joined them in forming the Teen Titans. She became a charter member of this team and remained a member for years, finding work as a professional model using the name Kory Anders.

How exactly does she hide her identity? Magical illusion? Skin makeup? Photoshopped images?

Comment: Having difficulties with the image insert from Chrome...

Comment: Never heard of this character before but find it funny that she's literally a "spice" girl.

Comment: Orange skin, green pupil-less eyes and that hair is "fairly normal"? Anyway, that image comes from the pre-Crisis (or just post-Crisis) New Teen Titans and IIRC she didn't even really try to hide her identity. "K/Cory Anders" was just a name she used in her professional life, not a secret identity.

Comment: Updated the image with one from 1980s showing the orange skin, and a mention of her using Kory Anders as a secret identity.

Comment: Note that the quote you added does not say she used "Kory Anders" as a secret identity, just that she worked under that name. As I said above, she used that name in her professional life, not as a secret identity. She didn't try to hide who she was.

Comment: @PatrickWynne: I suppose so. Would it be better if I simply asked how she got her skin looking that human for the modeling shots? :)

Comment: The text in the comic says "As for your looks, honey, 'way out' is in." I wonder if she, in fact, didn't hide her skin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Starfire's early appearances, [Donna Troy](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Donna_Troy_(New_Earth)) (AKA Wonder Girl) encouraged her to disguise herself so that she could be seen in public with Donna Troy, without Donna's own secret identity being given away.

> STARFIRE: This is a good world, I think. I'm glad to be here. Though so many of its customs still elude me. Donna and I are friends, yet before I see her I am supposed to dress differently than I am now. And I'm not supposed to call her Wonder Girl... yet, while fighting, I can't call her Donna. So confusing. So very confusing.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8, page 3.]
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8, page 5.]
>
> <sub>*[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_8)* (June, 1981)</sub>

Starfire found the idea of a dual identity confusing, though, and her efforts to maintain her own weren't very elaborate. She used the alias, 'Kory Anders,' wore civilian clothing (including sunglasses to cover her eyes), tried not to use her powers or speak of her alien origins when in disguise, and that was about the extent of it.

She made no attempt to disguise her natural complexion. In fact, her unusual skin colour was apparently a selling point in the eyes of the first fashion designer who hired her to model for him (Sergio de Levi), with him referring to her as his "golden girl."

> SERGIO DE LEVI: She's a 'beaut, I tell you. We're'a gonna sell a billion jeans with'a my golden girl! An' you, lady picture-taker--where you get this wonderful idea--puttin' my golden girl in'a space? It's'a wonderful!
>
> DONNA TROY: Oh, I don't know, Mr. de Levi--it just seemed natural, I guess.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #16, page 4.]
>
> <sub>*[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #16](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_16)* (February, 1982)</sub>

Not too long afterwards, she went out on her first date in public with [Dick Grayson](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Grayson_(New_Earth)) (AKA Robin/Nightwing). As before, she wore civilian clothing and sunglasses, but the idea of maintaining a clear separation between her superhero identity and her civilian one still didn't come naturally to her.

> STARFIRE: Dick, look over there! Isn't that the district attorney we met after the Brother Blood fight?
>
> DICK GRAYSON: Adrian Chase. Yeah, I thought he was a real hard-boiled case. Guess even he takes time off to relax.
>
> STARFIRE: Let's go over and say "hi!"
>
> DICK GRAYSON: Uh-uh. You forget. He met Starfire and Robin, not Kory Anders and Dick Grayson. Our civilian ID's aren't supposed to know him.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #26, page 9.]
>
> <sub>*[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #26](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_26)* (December, 1982)</sub>

In *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_7)* (April, 1985), we see her transition directly from the Kory Anders identity to Starfire on-panel, and all that entailed was her shedding her civilian attire to reveal her costume underneath. Her skin colour was the same shade of orange both before and after the transition.

> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7, page 3.]
>
> STARFIRE: If only I can find someplace to change into Starfire! Well, most everyone's looking up at the winged man... so a flash of starbolt light should hide my change!
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7, page 4.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7* (April, 1985)</sub>

In *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #35](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_35)* (September, 1987), she again wore sunglasses while out on a public date with Dick, suggesting that she was still attempting to maintain her secret identity at that point.

In *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_39)* (January, 1988), though, Donna stated that everyone knew Kory was a Titan, and Starfire ceased her efforts to pretend otherwise from that point forward. Her secret identity may have been blown as a result of her being arrested and put on trial after being framed for murder a couple of issues earlier, in *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #37](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_37)* (November, 1987).

> DONNA TROY: I do hope you didn't mind my turning down the nude layout. It would have been arty, but I still felt it was wrong.
>
> STARFIRE: It wouldn't have bothered me... nudity is not even thought about on Tamaran.
>
> DONNA TROY: Nudity doesn't bother me, either--but **everyone knows you're a Titan,** and even if they don't care, they do know... and the idea of a Titan posing nude... well, let's say the silent majority would probably find its tongue.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39, page 17.]
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39, page 18.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39* (January, 1988)</sub>

The second image in your question is from *[Action Comics Vol. 1 #612](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_612)* (August, 1988), which places it after the point at which Starfire had abandoned her secret identity. She also wasn't wearing sunglasses there, which is consistent with her no longer bothering to conceal her alien origins.

In *[New Titans Vol. 1 #57](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Titans_Vol_1_57)* (August, 1989), she openly used her energy powers while being filmed for a music video, and, again, didn't bother wearing sunglasses. Just after filming wrapped on the video, a Titans foe named [Wildebeest](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Wildebeest_Society) attacked the set, and Donna and Starfire both openly used their powers to fight him in front of the film crew.

In *[New Titans Vol. 1 #71](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Titans_Vol_1_71)* (November, 1990), Starfire was out in public with Dick again, but didn't bother concealing her eyes or powers. In fact, Dick was the one in disguise this time, wearing a wig, glasses, and a fake moustache, in an effort to keep his own dual identity a secret.

> [image: New Titans Vol. 1 #71, page 5.]
>
> <sub>*New Titans Vol. 1 #71* (November, 1990)</sub>

By *[New Titans Vol. 1 #96](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Titans_Vol_1_96)* (April, 1993), Dick had grown tired of having to wear a disguise whenever he was out in public with Starfire, and had [Mirage](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Miriam_Delgado_(Team_Titans)) pose as Nightwing and stage an attack on him in front of reporters and fans, so that he could openly date Starfire as Dick Grayson going forward, without the public suspecting that he was Nightwing himself.

> STARFIRE: Dick... what if Mirage, in her Nightwing guise, says she won't give me up?
>
> DICK GRAYSON: It doesn't matter what she says, Kory! It's her appearances here as Nightwing that will do the trick! Believe me, there're gonna be lots of pictures of us together to prove Dick Grayson isn't Nightwing. And then I can be with you, when ever... where ever I want... just me... without a disguise.
>
> [image: New Titans Vol. 1 #96, page 22.]
>
> <sub>*New Titans Vol. 1 #96* (April, 1993)</sub>

In *[New Titans Vol. 1 #98](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Titans_Vol_1_98)* (June, 1993), Starfire was approached by fans while dancing in a nightclub, and was alternately addressed as Miss Anders and Starfire.