# How did Starfire change the color of her skin?

Tags: dc, teen-titans

Related to [How does Koriand'r hide as Cory Anders?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/how-does-koriandr-hide-as-cory-anders), The panel I posted shows Starfire as Cory Anders, model. And it shows her with very human-looking skin, albeit still the same green eyes. Was there a time period when she did not have bright orange skin? Is it simply implied that the pictures were color corrected (reminding me of an old amusing anecdote about issues with green-skinned women on *Star Trek*)? Did the inker for the issue just get things wrong?

[image: Image showing Cory Anders, model, with human skin]

Most of my understanding of the Teen Titans is from the cartoon, and scattered issues.

Comment: [This answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/276475/109861) to the question [_How does Koriand'r hide as Cory Anders?_](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/how-does-koriandr-hide-as-cory-anders) sufficiently answers the question above. In _New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39_ (January, 1988), Donna Troy explicitly states that everyone already knows that Cory/Kory Anders is actually one of the (Teen) Titans. _Action Comics Vol. 1 #612_ (August, 1988), which is the comic book the scan included in the question above belongs to, came out months after. [1/2]

Comment: The fact that the modelling agency rep, in the scan included in the question above, is using one of Starfire's presumably latest fashion spreads in her attempt to convince Arisia to become a model, all the while treating the explicit fact that Arisia is an alien as trivial, only lends further credence to this. Starfire having a skin tone typical of a human in _Action Comics Vol. 1 #612_ (August, 1988) is most likely a screw up on the colourists' end. [2/2]

Comment: @SatyajitSen Rather than deleting and reposting the comment multiple times, why not provide an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### In the original comics, Starfire *didn't* change the colour of her skin.

I checked every issue of *[New Teen Titans Vol. 1](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1)*, plus every issue of *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2)* where she was still maintaining a secret identity, and in none of those issues was she ever depicted with anything other than orange skin, regardless of which guise she was in.

In this scene from *[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_8)* (June, 1981), for example, we see her disguising herself with civilian attire (including sunglasses to conceal her eyes) so she can meet Donna Troy at her workplace without being IDed as Starfire, but her skin is just as orange while she's in disguise as it was when she was in costume.

> STARFIRE: This is a good world, I think. I'm glad to be here. Though so many of its customs still elude me. Donna and I are friends, yet before I see her I am supposed to dress differently than I am now. And I'm not supposed to call her Wonder Girl... yet, while fighting, I can't call her Donna. So confusing. So very confusing.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8, page 3.]
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8, page 5.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #8* (June, 1981)</sub>

And in this scene from *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_7)* (April, 1985), we see her transition directly from the Kory Anders identity to Starfire on-panel, and all that entailed was her shedding her civilian attire to reveal her costume underneath. Her skin colour was the same shade of orange both before and after the transition.

> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7, page 3.]
>
> STARFIRE: If only I can find someplace to change into Starfire! Well, most everyone's looking up at the winged man... so a flash of starbolt light should hide my change!
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7, page 4.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #7* (April, 1985)</sub>

In this scene from *[New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #16](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_1_16)* (February, 1982), we see her modelling with orange skin, and the fashion designer who hired her refers to her as his "golden girl."

> SERGIO DE LEVI: She's a 'beaut, I tell you. We're'a gonna sell a billion jeans with'a my golden girl! An' you, lady picture-taker--where you get this wonderful idea--puttin' my golden girl in'a space? It's'a wonderful!
>
> DONNA TROY: Oh, I don't know, Mr. de Levi--it just seemed natural, I guess.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #16, page 4.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 1 #16* (February, 1982)</sub>

Note that, when in disguise, she wore sunglasses in all these examples, because while she was still maintaining a secret identity, she needed to conceal her eyes in order to somewhat pass for human.

She stopped bothering to conceal her eyes as Kory Anders after *[New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/New_Teen_Titans_Vol_2_39)* (January, 1988), because Donna told her that everyone knew she was a Titan anyway by that point. She continued to use the Kory Anders name, but it was effectively just a stage name from this point forward, rather than a secret identity.

> DONNA TROY: I do hope you didn't mind my turning down the nude layout. It would have been arty, but I still felt it was wrong.
>
> STARFIRE: It wouldn't have bothered me... nudity is not even thought about on Tamaran.
>
> DONNA TROY: Nudity doesn't bother me, either--but **everyone knows you're a Titan,** and even if they don't care, they do know... and the idea of a Titan posing nude... well, let's say the silent majority would probably find its tongue.
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39, page 17.]
>
> [image: New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39, page 18.]
>
> <sub>*New Teen Titans Vol. 2 #39* (January, 1988)</sub>

The image in your question is from *[Action Comics Vol. 1 #612](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_612)* (August, 1988), which places it after the point at which Starfire had abandoned her secret identity. The fact that she isn't wearing sunglasses in those panels supports this. So in all likelihood, she was meant to be her usual, orange-skinned self in those panels, but the colourist in that issue simply did a poor job of conveying that.

Comment: And I am sorry... I didn't mean for you to have to post everything over here. I was just indicating that the other answer didn't address the one point here, how she apparently changed the color of her skin, which was apparently a colorist issue.

Comment: I tweaked this answer to focus on the subject of Starfire's skin colour, whereas the answer I posted in the [other thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/154228/how-does-koriandr-hide-as-cory-anders) was a broader overview of her secret identity in general. I feel like that answer makes this thread redundant, though.

Answer (score 1):

This particular incident might be a coloring mistake.
However, when walking around as a civilian with the other Titans in their secret identities, I believe Starfire used a lot of makeup.  This was in some very early New Teen Titans.  It was never actually shown but there was nothing implied that this was any sort of forcibly mutated alien super power of hers.
In the Live Action, of course, she becomes orange only when using her powers, so she easily passes for human, different from her comic book character.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would appreciate a bit more backing explanation, although this is the best answer so far.

Comment: I looked through literally every issue of the original _New Teen Titans_ run, and found no evidence of Starfire using make-up to alter her complexion. Her skin was always consistently coloured orange whether she was in disguise or not.

Comment: And yet this is the only answer provided, so it will be getting a bounty.:)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Would you prefer if I posted my answer in the other thread here instead? I thought it was better to post it there, since it covers not just the issue of Starfire's skin colour, but her chosen method of disguise in general. Plus, this thread seems like a dupe of the other one to me.

Comment: @LogicDictates: Somehow, I missed that you posted there on the 15th, possibly since the interface changes for the message icon at the top. I've accepted it there. I think this question works alright on its own, although I suspect the answer to my question here is the comment that Satyajit Sen seemingly keeps deleting and reposting that it's a coloring error.